# Restriction of maximum 3 threads at a time

Tags: c#, multithreading, .net-4.0, task-parallel-library, task

I have following code that download html strings from various web-sites.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<string> URLsToProcess = new List<string>()
        {
            "http://www.microsoft.com",
            "http://www.stackoverflow.com",
            "http://www.google.com",
            "http://www.apple.com",
            "http://www.ebay.com",
            "http://www.oracle.com",
            "http://www.gmail.com",
            "http://www.amazon.com",
            "http://www.yahoo.com",
            "http://www.msn.com"
        };



        List<Task<string>> tURLs = new List<Task<string>>();

        foreach (string url in URLsToProcess)
        {
            Task<string> t = DownloadStringAsTask(new Uri(url));
            tURLs.Add(t);
        }

        Console.WriteLine("waiting now");

        Task.WaitAll(tURLs.ToArray());

        Console.WriteLine("download all done");
        foreach (Task<string> t in tURLs)
            Console.WriteLine(t.Result);
    }


    static Task<string> DownloadStringAsTask(Uri address)
    {
        TaskCompletionSource<string> tcs =
          new TaskCompletionSource<string>();
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        client.DownloadStringCompleted += (sender, args) =>
        {
            if (args.Error != null)
                tcs.SetException(args.Error);
            else if (args.Cancelled)
                tcs.SetCanceled();
            else
                tcs.SetResult(args.Result);
        };
        client.DownloadStringAsync(address);
        return tcs.Task;
    }
}
```

With this code its possible to launch 10 different threads to download data from all 10 different URLs. I would like to restrict it to max of 3 threads at a time. Any other requests should wait until one of thread get freed. Any ideas as to how to add this restriction?

Comment: A `Task` is *not* a `Thread`, if you want control over threads you should use a `ThreadPool` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3dasc8as.aspx

Comment: You should use Semaphore for this restriction.

Comment: are you trying to build your own thread pool?

Comment: @doctor: Not at all. To my understanding Task internally uses Threads from ThreadPool. I just want to restrict max number of parallel threads to 3.

Comment: Task != Thread. @johnsmith

Comment: you can get `tURLs` in chunks of size 3 and wait for them to complete.

Comment: @doctor: can you show some example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please look into [Data Parallelism](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537608(v=vs.110).aspx) vs. [Task Parallelism](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609(v=vs.110).aspx). You can use Parallel LINQ here:

```
var URLsToProcess = new List<string>
                    {
                        "http://www.microsoft.com",
                        "http://www.stackoverflow.com",
                        "http://www.google.com",
                        "http://www.apple.com",
                        "http://www.ebay.com",
                        "http://www.oracle.com",
                        "http://www.gmail.com",
                        "http://www.amazon.com",
                        "http://www.yahoo.com",
                        "http://www.msn.com"
                    };

Console.WriteLine("waiting now");

string[] tURLs = URLsToProcess
    .AsParallel()
    .WithDegreeOfParallelism(3)
    .Select(uri => this.DownloadStringAsTask(new Uri(uri)).Result)
    .ToArray();

Console.WriteLine("download all done");
foreach (string t in tURLs)
{
    Console.WriteLine(t);
}
```

Comment: What happen when some exception is thrown by one of the url?

Answer (score 1):

You Can use SemaphoreSlim class to limit the number of threads executed at a time.
 class Program
    {

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        List<string> URLsToProcess = new List<string>()
        {
            "http://www.microsoft.com",
            "http://www.stackoverflow.com",
            "http://www.google.com",
            "http://www.apple.com",
            "http://www.ebay.com",
            "http://www.oracle.com",
            "http://www.gmail.com",
            "http://www.amazon.com",
            "http://www.yahoo.com",
            "http://www.msn.com"
        };

        SemaphoreSlim ss = new SemaphoreSlim(3); //limit 3 threads at a time

        List<Task<string>> tURLs = new List<Task<string>>();


        foreach (string url in URLsToProcess)
        {
            //Task<string> t = DownloadStringAsTask(new Uri(url));
            //tURLs.Add(t);
            tURLs.Add((Task<string>)Task.Run(() =>
            {
                DownloadStringAsTask(new Uri(url));
                ss.Release();
            }));
        }

        Console.WriteLine("waiting now");

        Task.WaitAll(tURLs.ToArray());

        Console.WriteLine("download all done");
        foreach (Task<string> t in tURLs)
            Console.WriteLine(t.Result);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }



    static Task<string> DownloadStringAsTask(Uri address)
    {
        TaskCompletionSource<string> tcs =
          new TaskCompletionSource<string>();
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        client.DownloadStringCompleted += (sender, args) =>
        {
            if (args.Error != null)
                tcs.SetException(args.Error);
            else if (args.Cancelled)
                tcs.SetCanceled();
            else
                tcs.SetResult(args.Result);
        };

        client.DownloadStringAsync(address);

        return tcs.Task;
    }
}
```